# Gradle ant task for SCP does not pick properties from gradle.properties

Tags: gradle, ant, gradle-plugin

I created a gradle ant task based on example from [http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2009/12/gradle-goodness-using-optional-ant-task.html]

Below is the example code that works for me:

```
ant.scp(
   todir: 'myUserid:myPasswd@servername:/home/myUserid',
   trust:"true",
   verbose: 'true'
) {
   fileset(dir: 'work') {
      include(name: '**/**')
   }
}
```

For the todir: instead of `myUserid:myPasswd@servername:/home/myUserid` I used the following properties defined in gradle.properties file `"${remoteUser}:${remoteUserPasswd}@${remoteSSHMachine}:${remoteLocation}"`

This gives me an error

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.UnknownHostException: ${remoteSSHMachine}
```

remoteSSHMachine = server is already defined in the gradle.properties file so I'm not sure why  java.net.UnknownHostException exception should occur.

Amy help in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this demo: https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/43307004 - it all works fine, properties are resolved.

Comment: Thanks @Opal. I modified the code based on your example and it worked. I had to remove the double quotes in my properties file and it seem to have helped. I'll answer the question

Comment: Please, let me answer the question and you'll accept it. Is that ok?

Comment: Sure!. thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Thanks, I added the answer a moment ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say what exactly does not work, but I've prepared a [demo](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/43307004) that, admittedly, fails but with *unknown host exception* - properties from `gradle.properties` file are read correctly. Please compare your code with the demo, maybe it will help you somehow.

**EDIT**

It turned out that double quotes (`"`) in `gradle.properties` were messing things up.